# ActionResult parameter null control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, null, actionresult, url-parameters

How can i control ActionResult null parameter?.i'm trying nullable to id but not work.

CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult Languages(int id)
{
    if(id==null)
    {
      id = 0;
    }
    var query = from n in se.Languages
                orderby n.Language ascending
                select n;
    return View(query.Skip(id * 10).Take(10));
}
```

GLOBAL.ASAX:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        null,
        "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Languages" } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        null,
        "{controller}/{action}/page/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Languages", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

An `int` is not nullable try

```
public ActionResult Languages(int? id)

if(!id.HasValue)
    //...
```

or there's

```
public ActionResult Languages(int id = 0)
```

or you could provide the default in your routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "{controller}/{action}/page/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Languages", id = 0 } // Parameter defaults
);
```